# Prompt for password for encrypted root partition on every boot

Tags: macos, startup, password, encryption

I have a MacBook Air A2681 13" and I'd like to disable the auto unlock on the root partition so it prompts for a password on every boot before unlocking the root partition, loading the OS and showing the user login screen.

I have several users on my machine and would like to have a static local password and the recovery key option (like when using TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt/BitLocker/etc. on Windows), as far as I saw there was an option for this earlier but I could not find any relevant recent posts or questions about this.

---

I'm a new Mac user and I'd really appreciate any pointers and suggestions. If it can be done on the command line only, that's fine, too. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359005/how-to-force-disk-encryption-password-on-boot-for-all-users